# .htaccess: allow from - using dynamic IP - defining the static portion of my IP?

Tags: apache, ip-address, htaccess, dynamic

I'm looking to secure my phpMyAdmin dir from being accessed from other IPs than my own, albeit dynamic IP, let's say it is 191.164.1.xxx (xxx = being dynamic numbers).

Referring to the Apache directive `allow from` in .htaccess files, can I define only the first static numbers in order to allow anything starting with the defined IP numbers and let it accept any numbers in the same fashion a wildcard works in other contexts?

E.g. would would something like this work? : `allow from 191.164.1.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 then:

```
    allow from 191.164.1.0/24
```

Will allow all hosts in that subnet. 192.164.1.1, 192.164.1.2, 192.164.1.254

Comment: Thanks. Just a dumb question, the ending 24, should be 254, right?

Comment: No. That is CIDR notation. It is based off your network mask. You can cross reference yours with this list. http://old.tamasrepus.hotnudiegirls.com/pages/IPv4+CIDR+notation+cheat+sheet